# Does obstruction in one side of a Y/bifurcated inlet can cause asymmetric thrust?

Tags: aerodynamics

In an airplane with Y/bifurcated inlet If for whatever reason one side of the inlet is obstructed would this cause to roll/yaw or the aircraft would stay stable.

[image: Types of inlets]

And in another setup, If instead there are 2 engines at the beginning of the Y/bifurcated inlet and there is one engine failure, would this cause asymmetric thrust?

[image]

Comment: doubt it. inlets suck from all directions equally so they don't produce significant thrust. maybe from the force of air hitting the obstruction? but it's close to the aircraft's centerline -> not much torque generated by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In an airplane with Y/bifurcated inlet If for whatever reason one side of the inlet is obstructed would this cause to roll/yaw or the aircraft would stay stable?

I refer to the middle configuration in your picture.

If one side get clogged the following would be true:

- The clogged side would increase the aerodynamic drag; this might indeed create a yawning moment but, due to the short lever arm, the moment would be negligible; and there would be no problem at all for the rudder to counteract it;
- Half of the inlet area would miss; the working inlet might compensate for it but for sure not in those situations where a lot of thrust i.e. air is needed by the engine(s), at take off for example; surge of the engine can be expected in those cases;
- Flying in a sideslip toward the clogged side of the inlet would worsen the situation due to the fuselage "shadowing" the working inlet.

In the other case where we have two engines,   one left and one right, the situation would be similar, with the clogged inlet (i.e. not working engine) also creating drag and therefore yawing moment; also in this case the rudder should be able to compensate for it and this situation might even be the dimensioning condition of the rudder.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking that the inlets will make thrust because they're sucking air in. That's true, but jet engines push a lot more air out than they pull in. I'm not exactly sure of the ratio (it also varies for different engines), but it's more than you'd think.

As the comment on your question said, the obstruction might produce a torque, but it's close to the centerline/CM, so the vertical tail would be able to easily account for it.

In your second picture, the asymmetric thrust would probably double. (saying this because there are 2 engines, and they're not splitting a duct) It depends on the thrust of the engines and what power setting they are at, but it might start to become noticeable. If one engines is full AB, and the other is idle, you might start to feel asymmetric thrust. I'm not exactly sure how much air each jet engine would pull in, so I could be wrong.

If you want to get more complex, it also would depend on the size of the vertical stab, and the amount of rudder authority you have.

Answer (score 0):

The thrust will be symmetrical -- by the time the air goes through the engine, flow will be pretty uniform.

That said, non-uniform inflow will make it easier for the compressor or fan to stall and can cause other problems for the fan.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thrust-reversing (by running the motor backwards) is starting to become popular on Electric Ducted Fan radio-controlled model airplanes, which are often very realistic scale models of full-scale jet airplanes.  So in such a model of something like a F-35 or any other a/c with a Y/bifurcated inlet arrangement, there would surely be some noticeable yawing affect if one inlet was somehow blocked *while the motor was running backwards*!